# Does swiftui limit number of Spacer()?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This code is something similar to my current UI. I have alot of view in between of Spacer(). I notice that when i add alot of Spacer() i get this error //Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'HorizontalAlignment' that does not accept a closure// why is that?

```
import SwiftUI

 struct Phrases2: View {
   var body: some View {
    ZStack() {
        Text("")
        Text("")
        VStack() {
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is the number of views in the stack. [ViewBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) in SwiftUI allows you to have up to 10 views in the HStack/VStack/List.

You can avoid the issue using [Group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group)s:

```
VStack {
    Group {
        Text("")
        Spacer()
        Text("")
        Spacer()
        Text("")
        Spacer()
    }
    Group {
        Text("")
        Spacer()
        Text("")
        Spacer()
        Text("")
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. what about ForEach()? why it allow me to create so many text without group?

Comment: Using ForEach() is also good approach, here is a great article about it: 
 https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Group` to wrap 10 `Views`. Then use it again as follows:

```
Group {
    some 10 views
}
Group {
    some other 10 views
}
```